# Destroy a non-destructible base class?

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17, template-meta-programming

I'm working on an implementation of `optional<T>`, based on libc++'s `optional`, which contains a union like this:

```
template<class T, bool = is_trivially_destructible_v<T>>
struct __optional_destruct_base {
    union {
        char __null_state_;
        T __val_;
    };
    // no destructor needed; this class is trivially destructible
};

template<class T>
struct __optional_destruct_base<T, false> {
    union {
        char __null_state_;
        T __val_;
    };
    // destructor must be user-provided because the union's destructor is deleted
    ~__optional_destruct_base() {
        if (this->__engaged()) __val_.~T();
    }
};

template<class T>
class optional : private __optional_destruct_base<T> { ... };
```

Now here's where it gets hairy. I want both the `union` member and the implementation of `this->__engaged()` to be provided by *another* base class, called let's say `__optional_storage_base<T>`, with *another* `bool` template non-type parameter. I tried doing it like this:

```
template<class T, bool = is_foo_v<T>>
struct __optional_storage_base {
    union { char __null_state_; T __val_; };
    bool __engaged() const { puts("foo"); return false; }
};

template<class T>
struct __optional_storage_base<T, false> {
    union { char __null_state_; T __val_; };
    bool __engaged() const { puts("bar"); return false; }
};

template<class T, bool = is_trivially_destructible_v<T>>
struct __optional_destruct_base : __optional_storage_base<T>
{
};

template<class T>
struct __optional_destruct_base<T, false> : __optional_storage_base<T>
{
    ~__optional_destruct_base() {
        if (this->__engaged()) __val_.~T();
    }
};

template<class T>
class optional : private __optional_destruct_base<T> { ... };
```

But this causes a compiler error when instantiating `optional<some_T_which_is_not_trivially_destructible>`, because:

- `T` is not trivially destructible,
- therefore the union member of `__optional_storage_base<T>` has an implicitly deleted destructor,
- therefore `__optional_storage_base<T>` itself has a deleted destructor,
- therefore `__optional_destruct_base<T, false>` has a *base class* whose destructor is deleted;
- although I provide a definition for `__optional_destruct_base<T, false>::~__optional_destruct_base()`, that derived destructor will implicitly call the base class's destructor, which is deleted, so it fails to compile.

Is there any "elegant" way to work around this?  I know one practical solution, which is to explode the bool parameters:

```
template<class T, bool = is_trivially_destructible_v<T>, bool = is_foo_v<T>>
struct __optional_combinatorial_explosion_base { ... };

template<class T>
struct __optional_combinatorial_explosion_base<T, false, true> { ... };

template<class T>
struct __optional_combinatorial_explosion_base<T, true, false> { ... };

template<class T>
struct __optional_combinatorial_explosion_base<T, true, true> { ... };
```

I also have a nebulous idea about applying the CRTP somehow, but I haven't figured out how to make that work.

Any ideas that don't involve `__optional_combinatorial_explosion_base`?

Comment: Do note that names starting with double underscore are reserved to the implementation.

Comment: Since both `__engaged` functions returns `false`, your are working hard for nothing (assuming that `puts` is just for testing purpose). **And it does not make sense to move the union in a base when then purpose of the derived class is to decide if a destructor should be provided.**

Comment: @Quuxplusone If you know that you should not start names with double underscores, then why you do it anyway? **Please, fix your code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also have a nebulous idea about applying the CRTP somehow, but I haven't figured out how to make that work.

I have now figured it out! At least I believe this works. It passes libc++'s test suite.

Wherever we put the union, that class's destructor is going to get deleted by default (if `T` is not trivially destructible). Whoever is in charge of the union member, that class *must* also be in charge of the conditionally trivial destructor. So we *must* keep the union directly inside `__optional_destruct_base<T>` (since that's the class we have chosen to be in charge of the destructor).

However, we can successfully split out the responsibility for the `__engaged()` member function! We start by moving the code for the destructor back down into the class with the union member:

```
template<class T, bool = is_trivially_destructible_v<T>>
struct __optional_destruct_base {
    union { char __null_state_; T __val_; };
};

template<class T>
struct __optional_destruct_base<T, false> {
    union { char __null_state_; T __val_; };
    ~__optional_destruct_base() {
        if (this->__engaged()) __val_.~T();
    }
};

template<class T, bool = is_foo_v<T>>
struct __optional_engaged_base : __optional_destruct_base <T>
{
    bool __engaged() const { puts("foo"); return false; }
};

template<class T>
struct __optional_engaged_base<T, false> : __optional_destruct_base<T>
{
    bool __engaged() const { puts("bar"); return false; }
};

template<class T>
class optional : private __optional_engaged_base<T> { ... };
```

This *almost* compiles, except for the line in the destructor that is trying to call `__engaged()`:

```
    ~__optional_destruct_base() {
        if (this->__engaged()) __val_.~T();  // oops!
    }
```

Here the base class is trying to call a method that is implemented only in the derived class. So we apply the CRTP! Except that we don't even need to pass in a template parameter, because we *know* who's going to be providing the `__engaged` method.

```
    ~__optional_destruct_base() {
        auto *__self = static_cast<__optional_engaged_base<T> *>(this);
        if (__self->__engaged()) __val_.~T();
    }
```

And there we have it! I'm still not sure if it's possible to write a destructor for a class with a non-destructible base class... but it *is* possible to work around that limitation in my specific case, without running into a combinatorial explosion of template specializations that all want to be "most ancestral".